# Preview Android Studio Ocultar elementos

Tags: android-studio

Me encuentro que es bastante molesto tener el menu principal en el preview de mi app en el IDE Android Studio

Esto no deja maquetar tranquilamente sin tener que borrarlo y volver a ponerlo para poder ver los elementos traseros

¿Existe alguna forma de ocultarlo en el preview? 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elimina el atributo `tools:openDrawer="start"` en el elemento `<DrawerLayout>` para ocultar el drawer:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout android:id="@+id/drawer"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    tools:openDrawer="start" <------ELIMINA EL ATRIBUTO PARA QUE SE OCULTE DEL DESIGNER
>
```